# Firefox. Firebug Console - suppress "Received Focus" "Lost Focus" messages

Tags: firefox, firebug

**How do I get rid of these....**

[image]

Filtering doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Shif+A in Firefox or go to Tools->Add-ons.
Find "Firefocus". Press Options button and untick "Log Focus Events".

[image: Log Focus Events option in Firefocus]